# Collapsing Toolbar not working as desired

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I am working on Collapsing Toolbar. I added a RecyclerView below the Toolbar.
I am facing few issues:

1. On scrolling up the RecylerView the Toolbar must also scroll up but it isn't. to scroll up the Toolbar we need to touch the Toolbar and scroll it up.

[image: on scrolling the Toolbar isn't going up]

2. When my Toolbar is scrolled down my last element gets hidden.

[image: See the last element gets hidden]

Following is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the xml for nexted scrollview with recyler view which is included in the above xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: do not place RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView.

Comment: You can also use RelativeLayout instead of your NestedScrollView. I figured this out when trying to add a recycler viewer in my project just below the toolbar

Comment: then where do i add the recycler view?

Comment: ohk @KaranMer thank you so much. such a silly mistake . and where ever i saw that recycler view was inside nestedview. thank u so much. i wasted 3 days into this silly thing

Comment: and its working. but when i scroll down and if the appbar isnt expanded then it stops at the 1st item of the list and then i have to again scroll it once more to expand it? how to solve that

Comment: I think thats the default behaviour

Comment: there is no method to get appbar expanded on fling?

Comment: I think you should ask another new question for that, I haven't used collapsing toolbar much, it was this common mistake you were doing so i pointed it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this: replace the `<include>` with below `RecyclerView` and get rid of `NestedScrollView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behaviour="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

All you need is **`app:layout_behaviour="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`**.